# Largest palindrome product python

Tags: python

What I am attempting to do is find the largest palindrome made from the product of two 3-digit numbers. (which the code below kind of does) now i know the largest number is 906609 or 913 * 993. Now the problem I am running in to is that the code below will not find that number. As the code is right now it finds 90909 as the largest

```
for x in xrange(0, 1000):
    for y in xrange(0, 1000):
        #print '%d * %d = %d' % (x, y, x*y)
        num = (x * y)
        q = list(str(x * y))
        q.reverse()
        w = q
        #print(w)
        s = filter(str.isdigit, repr(q))
        q = int(s)
        #print(q)
        if num == q:
            hold3 = num, q, x , y
            print(hold3)

print(hold3)
```

Now if I change the number in the for to 914 and 994. It will give me the answer of 906609.
I would like to know why I am getting two different number with this. Sorry I am very new to python.

```
for x in xrange(0, 914):
    for y in xrange(0, 994):
        #print '%d * %d = %d' % (x, y, x*y)
        num = (x * y)
        q = list(str(x * y))
        q.reverse()
        w = q
        #print(w)
        s = filter(str.isdigit, repr(q))
        q = int(s)
        #print(q)
        if num == q:
            hold3 = num, q, x , y
            print(hold3)

print(hold3)
```

Comment: You should be using `xrange` not `x range`

Comment: x range is a typo, it would not run otherwise

Comment: @MartinKonecny thanks, when I was typing this is I forgot to keep it as one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both codes find 906609. However, the first code overwrites it with a later result.

You need to check whether the current palindrome you've found is bigger than what you've previously found, and if not ignore it.

Slight tweak to your code:

```
largest = 0
for x in xrange(0, 1000):
    for y in xrange(0, 1000):
        #print '%d * %d = %d' % (x, y, x*y)
        num = (x * y)
        q = list(str(x * y))
        q.reverse()
        w = q
        #print(w)
        s = filter(str.isdigit, repr(q))
        q = int(s)
        #print(q)
        if num == q and num > largest:
            largest = num
            hold3 = num, q, x , y
            print(hold3)

print(hold3) # correctly shows 906609 is the largest number
```

Comment: thanks! works perfect, didn't ever realize i was overwriting the largest. thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

This happens because `906609` is the largest palindromic product, but *not* the palindromic number corresponding to the largest value of `x` (`999`, with `y == 91`).

Check before updating:

```
        if num == q and num > hold3[0]:
```

You will need to initialise e.g. `hold3 = [0]`.